# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''soft_name'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, syntax-error

I am having this error in the following code. Please tell me my mistake.

**Error**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''soft_name', 'soft_ver', 'soft_size', 'sdesc', 'slink') VALUES ('h', ' ', ' ', '' at line 1

**Code**

```
<?php
$sname=$_POST['name'];
if (!empty($_POST['ver'])) $ver=$_POST['ver']; else $ver=" ";
if (!empty($_POST['ssize'])) $ssize=$_POST['ssize']; else $ssize=" ";
if (!empty($_POST['description'])) $desc=$_POST['description']; else $desc=" ";
if (!empty($_POST['link'])) $slink=$_POST['link']; else $slink=" ";

mysql_select_db('1027593',mysql_connect('','',''));
$qry="INSERT INTO downloads ('soft_name', 'soft_ver', 'soft_size', 'sdesc', 'slink') VALUES ('".$sname."', '".$ver."', '".$ssize."', '".$desc."', '".$slink."')";
mysql_query($qry);
echo  mysql_error();
die();
?>
```

Comment: You are wide-open to SQL injection. Please use a prepared statement and the PDO MySQL library to avoid problems in the future.

Comment: Your quotes are incorrect, you're using double quotes inside double quotes (without escaping them). Use single quotes for your variable names and also take @Hidde advice and use PDO :)

Answer (score 1):

> Change Query

```
$qry="INSERT INTO downloads ('soft_name', 'soft_ver', 'soft_size', 'sdesc', 'slink') VALUES ('".$sname."', '".$ver."', '".$ssize."', '".$desc."', '".$slink."')";
```

to

```
$qry="INSERT INTO downloads (`soft_name`, `soft_ver`, `soft_size`, `sdesc`, `slink`) VALUES ('".$sname."', '".$ver."', '".$ssize."', '".$desc."', '".$slink."')";
```

your mistake is you add a single quote(') in field name and it is not allow in sql field.

hope this solution help for you

Comment: Thank you so much.
I actually solved it, the problem was I used desc as a column name which was a reserved word which I changed to sdesc which still didn't worked, so I changed it to description. Now it's working.